# Getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm getting an exception after changing log4j-api and log4j-core JARs  from 2.17.0 to 2.19.0,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil
```

Comment: Please provide the full exception stacktrace, it generally contains details why it couldn't initialize.

Comment: @vishnu: the initialization problem is probably caused by the interaction with your other dependencies (e.g. old OSGI APIs). We fixed two such problems in 2.20.0.

Comment: I tried 2.20.0 log4j version. It seems to be working